# has_many build AssociationTypeMismatch Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Another newb question.   A Band has_many Albums.   I'm getting the error:

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Band(#70076964285020) expected,
>   got "1" which is an instance of String(#12787800)):
>   app/controllers/albums_controller.rb:20:in `create'

... which is the build line in #create

albums controller

```
def new
  binding.pry
  @band = Band.find(params[:band])
  authorize @band, :admin?

  @album = Album.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

def create
  binding.pry
  @band = Band.find(params[:album][:band].to_i)
  authorize @band, :admin?

  @album = @band.albums.build(album_params)    

  if @album.save

    @albums = @band.albums
    #@eps = @band.eps
    #songs = @band.songs

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  else
    @fail = "fail"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end


def album_params
    params.require(:album).permit(:band, :album_name, :album_release_date, :etc)
end
```

the form:

```
<%=simple_form_for(@album, remote: true, :authenticity_token => true, format: :js) do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :band, :value => @band.id %>

    <%= f.input :album_name %>

    <%= f.input :album_release_date %>

    <%= f.input :etc %>

    <div id="albumsubmit">
      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Create Album", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

schema

```
create_table "albums", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "band_id"
    t.string "album_name"
    t.string "album_release_date"
    t.index ["band_id"], name: "index_albums_on_band_id"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you passing to **save** method param with that have has_many   Association he expect the instance of "band", just set the param name to **band_id**

here:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :band, :value => @band.id %>
```

to:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :band_id, :value => @band.id %>
```

and here:

```
params.require(:album).permit(:band, :album_name, :album_release_date, :etc)
```

to:

```
params.require(:album).permit(:band_id, :album_name, :album_release_date, :etc)
```

Comment: also here `@band = Band.find(params[:album][:band].to_i)` :)

Comment: Right on, thanks.   I resolved it 10 minutes prior by removing :band from the params, something was mixing it up with the association i guess, and seems the band_id field gets imputed automatically from the build.